# Why does this ajax fail?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have used the same ajax code in a  file and it works. But the same code does not work in the other files.

This is my code

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: "GET",
     url: "get_child.php?pc_id="+pc_id.toString(),

}).done(function(option)  {
    alert("done");
}).fail(function(option)  {
    alert("fail");
});
```

please tell me what all could be wrong

works here:view-source:http://schoolspam.com/addTeacher.php
does not work here:view-source:http://schoolspam.com/school/oppa_alla_36/

Comment: Without seeing more code it's impossible to say, but what is `pc_id`?  Put an alert (console.log is better) before the ajax call to check the value.  Also, the last comma (after toString) will cause an issue in IE - get rid of that to be on the safe side.

Comment: maybe because the path to `get_child.php` is no longer the same?

Comment: add a details error handler `$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_child.php?pc_id="+pc_id.toString(),
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert('error:' + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText)
    }
}).done(function(option)  {
    alert("done");
}).fail(function(option)  {
    alert("fail");
});`

Comment: Well, what errors do you get? Browsers have built-in debuggers (IE8+, Chrome, Firefox, etc.). They often log any issues with requests, or at least let you watch "Network" to debug it yourself. Example: [Chrome](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html).

Comment: what all code should i post? the path is the same. the query always fails

Comment: just posted the sources of the two files.

Comment: Don't link to files that are likely to change when you fix them as part of a question. Put the relevant content in the question. And stop just saying "it fails": How does it fail? Look at the HTTP requests being made, see if are as you expect, look at the error messages in the JS console, look at the error messages in your server logs, etc.

Comment: giving absolute path didnt work

Answer (score 2):

remove the last comma? on .toString()

Comment: It's bit harsh to downvote this.  It *will* cause it to fail in IE so it could be his problem.

Comment: I agree. When "does not work" is all we know, pointing a potential cause of non-workiness cannot be considered not useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of the page you have [`linked to`](http://schoolspam.com/school/oppa_alla_36/) you have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=Óhttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.jsÓ type=Ótext/javascriptÓ></script>
```

Here you have included jQuery twice and in the second inclusion you have some weird looking characters. Simply get rid of the second line.

Also your AJAX call is wrong. You have the following:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_child.php?pc_id="+pc_id.toString(),
    done: function(option)  {
        alert("done");
    },
    fail: function(option)  {
        alert("fail");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

which should be:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_child.php?pc_id="+pc_id.toString()
}).done(function(option)  {
    alert("done");
}).fail(function(option)  {
    alert("fail");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be in using a relative path for the `url`, which are relative to the current address.

So, each of pages you listed will expect to find `get_child.php` in a different location:

```
http://schoolspam.com/addTeacher.php ->
http://schoolspam.com/get_child.php
```

```
http://schoolspam.com/school/oppa_alla_36/ ->
http://schoolspam.com/school/oppa_alla_36/get_child.php
```

You can try instead specifying the `url` from root. Since the script seems to be in the root directory, it would just need a leading `/` added.

```
url: "/get_child.php?pc_id="+pc_id.toString()
```

Comment: Wat??  If the script is already in the root folder then prefixing the url with `/` will have no effect.

Comment: @Archer Client-side URL paths don't automatically start at root, unless they have a leading `/`. The default is to start at the directory of the current page -- sure, `/` for the one page, but `/school/oppa_alla_36/` for the other. This is the same for `<a href>`, `<script src>`, etc.

Comment: I know that Jonathan.  The script is already in the root folder though, as I said, so prefixing it with `/` in this case will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: @Archer The page at `/school/oppa_allo_36/` ***will not*** look for `get_child.php` in the root directory with the current relative path. It would need to use `"../../get_child.php"`. Otherwise, it needs to be an absolute path, `"/get_child.php"` or `//schoolspam.com/get_child.php"`.

Comment: I really do understand relative and absolute paths.  Keeps your knickers on :).  He's changed the question since my post.  He originally said everything was in the root.